# Finding every element of order $2$ in $D_6$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Find every element of order $2$ in
$$
D_6 = \{e, \sigma, \sigma^2, \sigma^3, \sigma^4, \sigma^5, \rho, \sigma\rho, \sigma^2\rho, \sigma^3\rho, \sigma^4\rho, \sigma^5\rho\}
$$
The answers say that the elements of order $2$ are: $\sigma^3$, $\rho$, $\sigma\rho$, $\sigma^2\rho$, $\sigma^3\rho$, $\sigma^4\rho$, $\sigma^5\rho$.

I can see why this is the case for $\sigma^3$ as $\sigma^3\sigma^3 = \sigma^6 = 1$. Similarly $\rho\rho = \rho^2 = 1$. However I am having problems conceptually grasping why $\sigma\rho$, $\sigma^2\rho$, $\sigma^3\rho$, $\sigma^4\rho$, $\sigma^5\rho$ are of order $2$.

Comment: Note that between a single pair of dollar signs you can fit a lot more math than you are currently doing. Instead of `$\sigma^3\sigma^3$ = $\sigma^6$ = 1`, you can write `$\sigma^3\sigma^3 = \sigma^6 = 1$`, and it looks much better: $\sigma^3\sigma^3 = \sigma^6 = 1$.
And `D$_6$ = {*e*, $\sigma$, $\sigma^2$, $\sigma^3$, $\sigma^4$, $\sigma^5$, $\rho$, $\sigma$$\rho$, $\sigma^2\rho$, $\sigma^3\rho$, $\sigma^4\rho$, $\sigma^5\rho$}` is a tad messy.
Try `$$D_6 = \{e, \sigma, \sigma^2, \sigma^3, \sigma^4, \sigma^5, \rho, \sigma\rho, \sigma^2\rho, \sigma^3\rho, \sigma^4\rho, \sigma^5\rho\}$$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometrically it's obvious, as $D_6$ is the group of symmetries of a hexagon, and the $\sigma^k\rho$ terms are the six reflection symmetries. They clearly all have order 2.

Algebraically, in order to solve this, you have to know that in any dihedral group we have $\sigma\rho=\rho\sigma^{-1}$ (which in $D_6$ also happens to equal $\rho\sigma^5$). That way we get, for instance
$$
(\sigma\rho)^2=(\sigma\rho)(\sigma\rho)\\
=(\rho\sigma^{-1})(\sigma\rho)=\rho^2=e
$$
The higher powers of $\sigma$ work more or less exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Label the vertices of the hexagon $0,\dots,5$. A rotation maps vertex $k$ to $k+1\pmod 6$, and a reflection maps vertex $k$ to $6-k\pmod 6$.

Then $\sigma^k\rho$ maps vertex $j$ to $j+k \pmod 6$ and then to $6-(j+k)=6-j-k \pmod 6$. Repeating the operations maps $6-j-k \pmod 6$ to $6-j-k+k=6-j \pmod 6$, and then back to $j$, i.e. where it started.